# Why doesn't the import in the following Jupytor Notebook work?

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, spell-checking

[image]

So I used ! sys instead of use "pip" directly. From what I searched, this should be the best practice.

But the second cell doesn't print anything.
I got the code from this web, it should work. But can anyone tell me why it didn't.
[geekforgeek](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/spelling-checker-in-python/)

Comment: "*I got the code from this web, it should work.*" Not necessary. Internet is full of bad, broken code, sometimes deliberately evil. If you blindly copy code from the Net without understanding it sooner or later it will destroy your files.

Comment: I am not saying all things from Internet will work. Please don't over thinking those sentences.

Answer (score 2):

There shouldn't be a space between `-` and `m`:

```
python -m pip install thing
python - m pip install thing # NOT this
```

Otherwise the dash `-` will be treated as "read input from `stdin`", I presume.